# Establishing if Memory Leak on Embedded Device

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, embedded, embedded-linux

I have an linux based embedded device on which I am running a QT GUI application as well as a second application controlling some hardware. The two communicate with each other via TCP.

I have recently run a system test where I stimulate the QT application using Squish for an entire week. At the start and end of my test I extract the smap and pmap files for each of my two processes. Likewise I extract the meminfo file.

How might I compare the before and after files to get a rough idea as to whether I have a memory leak problem for the device as a whole? Also, if a leak were detected, how might I make a rough, rough estimate as to when the device will stop functioning correctly?

Comment: every leak is unique detection, side effects, failure rates, etc...

Answer (score 0):

> How might I compare the before and after files to get a rough idea as
>   to whether I have a memory leak problem for the device as a whole?

**Answer:**

I think you might need to know how much memory device driver used in kernel space so slab info is the place which it is worthwhile to look into.

Initially,you can do(running a script):

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i Slab
```

to monitor the value(any increase after long time running).

If it does, you can compare the leaked one with the one before leaking with the help of `cat /proc/slabinfo` by looking into each entry.

If you familiar the name of each entry, (if you are sure it must be a leak in this driver and have a rough idea of how it allocate memory) you can do a reasonable guess.

for example

```
size-4194304           0      0 4194304    1
kmem_cache           136    180    128   30
```

if "kmem_cache entry" is leaking, then your driver might call kmem_cache_create and kmem_cache_alloc() but not free

if it is "size-4194304", you driver might call get_zeroed_page or _ _get_free_pages but not free.

> how might I make a rough, rough estimate as to when the device will
>   stop functioning correctly

**Answer:**

if your user space doesn't leak any memory and the leak only happens in your driver, you can use "free" command to get how much free system memory is available.

Then you can roughly calculate how long it will be used up:

(Total free memory(kbyte)/memory leak_speed(kbyte/s)) = number of seconds.

,however kernel will complain before that.